# How to count number of symbols like @,#,+ etc in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to write a code to count number of  letters,characters,space and symbols in a `String`. But I don't know how to count Symbols.

Is there any such function available in java?

Comment: See here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605038/java-counting-letters-in-a-sentence You just have to inverse and count all skiped characters that are no letters.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Read the Java tutorial on [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html](strings).

Answer (score 2):

That very much depends on your *definition* of the term **symbol**.

A straight forward solution could be something like

```
Set<Character> SYMBOLS = Set.of('@', ' ', ....
for (int i=0; i < someString.length(); i++} {
  if (SYMBOLS.contains(someString.charAt(i)) {
```

That iterates the chars `someString`, and checks each char whether it can be found within that predefined SYMBOLS set.

Alternatively, you could use a regular expression to define "symbols", or, you can rely on a variety of existing definitions. When you check the regex [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) language for java, you can find

```
\w  A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]
\W  A non-word character: [^\w]
```

for example. And various other shortcuts that denote this or that set of characters already.

Comment: I didn't know you could do `Set.of` directly. I've always seen it written like `Set.<Character>of`

Comment: @ShashwatKhanna Well, these "type hints" are mostly no longer needed, as java type inference has been improved continuously over the last years. And as "Set.of()" requires java9, I am pretty sure, it should work (albeit, disclaimer: I didn't test it myself).

Answer (score 0):

Please post what you have tried so far

If you need the count of individual characters - you better iterate the string and use a map to track the character with its count

> Or

You can use a regex if just the overall count would enough like below

```
while (matcher.find() ) {count++}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to just iterate over the String and compare each character to their ASCII value

```
String str = "abcd!@#";
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        {
            if(33==str.charAt(i))
                System.out.println("Found !");
        }
```

lookup here for ASCII values https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html